# xCode 7.3.1 beta - Appstore submission error

Tags: ios, xcode7.2, xcode7-beta5

[image]I have developed application with 3d touch features and am trying to upload into itunes but I couldn't perform that with my xcode7.3.1 beta software an di tried with xcode 7.2.1 also. can any one help me to out of this issue.

Comment: That's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I want to upload the application which supports the latest version of OS features. I have xcode 7.3 beta. While uploading into appstore ipa file is not generating

Comment: And you don't get *any* error messages?

Comment: Yes. While clicking to export its quitting. and I tried from 7.2 Xcode its not exporting ipa which is stops after compiling status

Comment: And there is nothing in the logs (see `Console.app`)?

Comment: its not connecting with itunes. and is that possible to upload app from xcode 7 series?

Comment: Yes, but not with a beta version.

Comment: Bu we are trying with xcode 7.2.1 original version only but after completing of compiling source files its not moving to archive. like am getting upto 650 of 650 source file compiling... after that nothing is happening

Comment: Without an error message it's anyone's guess.

Comment: trojanfoe.. I couldn't get any response from xcode its like keep on loading after that point

Comment: @trojanfoe- see my attached screen above, after that line my archive was got stoped

Comment: Are you running a beta OS X?

Comment: are u asking abt my xcode version or

Comment: No, the OS X version (your operating system).

Comment: no original version only

Answer (score 0):

I had similar, but not the same problems. It kept in a loop.

What i did is first archive your build and then try again to upload.

Comment: for me the project is going to archive.

Comment: So when you push product > archive > chrash ?

Comment: see my attached screen above, after that line my archive was got stoped

Comment: try and clcean your build folder